# Getting a blank screen on kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Following a basic tutorial on kivy, tried running it but the kivy window that pops up is blank, .kv file is in lowercase, so no problems there I guess. Searched all over for a solution but am getting nothing

Installed all the packages correctly, double-checked kv file

```
#main.py#
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class CustomWidget(Widget):
    pass

class CustomWidgetApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return CustomWidget()

customWidget = CustomWidgetApp()

customWidget.run()
```

customwidget.kv:

```
#customwidget.kv#
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 150, 50
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: 'bkgrd-down-color.png'
    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1

<CustomWidget>:
    CustButton:
        text: "Random"
        pos: root.x, 200
    CustButton:
        text: "Buttons"
        pos: 200, root.y
    CustButton:
        text: "Buttons"
        pos: 200, 400
```

Expecting a window with 3 buttons

Logs if it helps:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in 
C:\Users\----\AppData\Roaming\SPB_16.6\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-01-11_28.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC 
v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, 
img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 398.72'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <32768>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

Comment: That is the behavior I would expect if Kivy cannot find your `.kv` file. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I also used self.load and still did not get anything